# Distribute an app that contains static libraries to appstore

Tags: ios, app-store, appstore-approval

I'm using `sqlcipher` library for my app. This is what I get after "Product -> Build -> For Profiling".

[image]

Normally, without `sqlcipher`, I just compress the `FastTaxi` file and upload it to appstore via `Xcode's App Loader` tool. (I followed lynda's tutorial)

How can I distribute my app now ? should I zip the file with all the lib files too ?

Or use `Product -> Archive -> Distribute to appstore` ?

Please help, thank you.

Comment: Always just use Product -> Archive -> Distribute to App Store when you want to distribute to the App Store. In Apple world, applications do what they say. No need to second guess or do a whole load of manual steps.

Answer (score 1):

Static libraries are compiled directly into the final executable, so you don't need to worry about it.  If you built it and it runs, just distribute it as you normally would.

Answer (score 1):

the **REQUIRED parts** (only needed classes...) of all static libs you use are compiled into the app -- so there is **only one artifact needed**

BUT if you compile the library e.g. as a subproject, a copy of the full library is put into the archive next to your app. ithis is NOT needed but will make it impossible for the integrated uploader to work as no ipa can be made.

In the library project, set the **Build setting 'Skip Install'** to YES. the lib wont be put into the archive and with only the app, the uploader works fine.